# HMAC_DRBG algorithm for Java SecureRandom: only possible in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-8, java-9, java-security, secure-random

I tried running the codes below using Java 8:

```
final Set<String> algorithms = Security.getAlgorithms("SecureRandom");

for (String algorithm : algorithms) {
  System.out.println(algorithm);
}

final String defaultAlgorithm = new SecureRandom().getAlgorithm();

System.out.println("default: " + defaultAlgorithm);
```

I got the ff:

```
HASHDRBG
IBMSECURERANDOM
SHA1PRNG
SHA256DRBG
SHA512DRBG
default: SHA1PRNG
```

What if company policy states that we need to use HMAC_DRBG? is there a way to implement this in Java 8? I heard this could only be done in Java 9. is it true?

Comment: There is an `DRBG` implementation in Java 9: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/oracleproviders.htm#JSSEC-GUID-9DC4ADD5-6D01-4B2E-9E85-B88E3BEE7453 See also the JDK Enhancement Proposal (JEP) that introduced it: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/273

Comment: @Robert how about in Java 8? can it be done too? or just in Java 9?

Comment: According to the JEP documentation it is a pure Java implementation, hence backporting to Java 8 should be possible, but then it is up to you to do so and don't forget also to backport the unit tests using the test vectors. In any way In my opinion the effort you need should better be used to start the migration of your application to Java 11 (latest LTS release).

Comment: sorry i dont get it .if those algorithms are only available in Java 9, how would backporting t0 Java 8 enable using it?. is there like an add on or something?